# How to call API at particular event after return in Controller, Laravel Lumen?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, lumen

**We implementing a system in Laravel Lumen:**

complete flow Image:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rFdkUwUaTQ4DGQaxXveu6CFylg1o1oLN/view?usp=sharing

1. assume the client hit the POST API 1 that we defined at our server end and has to use that POST API 1 response at the server end.  [***Note: on this POST API 1 event we have to automatically trigger  another POST API 2 but after return 202***.] [the client will call the server APIs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrSQ7.png)
2. Now as a server, we have to send the client as response a response as acknowledgment, like Yes we got your API hit. In the form of code, we will return status code = 202  with the message = Request Accepted for POST API 1. [server will send an acknowledgment to the client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1sWj.png)
3. now POST API 1 returns 202, so POST API 2 will have to trigger at the server end, in body server will use POST API 1 response data [server called the POST API 2 of the client with the help of POST API 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08GH4.png)
4. the client will do the same as the server, he also sends acknowledgment with the status 202, with the message request accepted [client acknowledgment to the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqQjh.png)

Here the flow is completed.

> api.php file
>
> ```
> <?php
> /** @var \Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Router $router */
>
> /*
> |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
> | Application Routes
> |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
> |
> | Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
> | It is a breeze. Simply tell Lumen the URIs it should respond to
> | and give it the Closure to call when that URI is requested.
> |
> */
>
> // clients will call this API
> $router->group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () use ($router) {
>     $router->post('API1', ['uses' => 'HIP\GatewayApi@api1']);
> });
> ```

> GatewayApi.php
>
> ```
> namespace App\Http\Controllers\HIP;
> use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
> use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue;
> use App\Jobs\Job;
>
> public function api1(){
>     $data = Request::all();
>     // here we use event, queues, jobs, but didnt work, i m showing you one of the example of it
>     Queue::push(new Job($data));
>     return response()->json(['message' => 'Request Accepted'], 202);
> }
>
> public function API2(){
>     // server will call the client api and client will return 202 reponse
> }
> ```

> Job.php
>
> ```
> <?php
>
> namespace App\Jobs;
>
> use App\Http\Controllers\HIP\GatewayApi;
> use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
> use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
> use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
> use Log;
> use App\Events\OnCallBackApi;
>
> class ProcessAbhaCallback implements ShouldQueue
> {
>     use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;
>
>     protected $data;
>
>     /**
>      * Create a new job instance.
>      *
>      * @param  array  $data
>      * @return void
>      */
>     public function __construct(array $data)
>     {
>         $this->data = $data;
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * Execute the job.
>      *
>      * @return void
>      */
>     public function handle()
>     {
>          event(new OnCallBackApi($this->data));        
>     }
> }
> ```

> OnCallBackApi.php
>
> ```
> <?php
>
> namespace App\Events;
> class OnCallBackApi extends Event
> {
>     /**
>      * Create a new event instance.
>      *
>      * @return void
>      */
>
>     public $event;
>     public function __construct($event)
>     {
>         $this->event = $event;  
>     }
> }
> ```

> SendOnCallBackApi.php ---> Listener
>
> ```
> <?php
>
> namespace App\Listeners;
>
> use App\Events\OnCallBackApi;
> use App\Http\Controllers\HIP\GatewayApi;
> use Log;
>
> class SendOnCallBackApi
> {
>     /**
>      * Create the event listener.
>      *
>      * @return void
>      */
>     public function __construct()
>     {
>         //
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * Handle the event.
>      *
>      * @param  OnCallBackApi  $event
>      * @return void
>      */
>     public function handle(OnCallBackApi $event)
>     {
>         $api = new GatewayApi();
>         $api->API2($data);
>     }
> }
> ```

##### issue

so try to do the same as mentioned, but the API2 is hit first, and then the 202 status returns for API 1.

##### Excepting:

want API 1 returns first with 202 and then API 2 needs to be hit by the server to the client

Comment: Why are you not want to set logic if some condition fail then call another function. i don't think to call another api.

Comment: we are integrating with ABHA entity they are follow this approach, so we have to follow same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can send the api1 response 202 and send after that the api2 response like this :

```
public function api1(){
    $data = Request::all();
    //send the api1 response to client.
    response()->json(['message' => 'Request Accepted'], 202)->send();
    //send the api2 response
    Queue::push(new Job($data));
}
```